# Implicit int size indication or explicit?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, 32bit-64bit

Currently my application is 32-bit.

This means that all tables running on SQL Server 2008 IDs' are `INT` that is equal to `System.Int32` and everywhere where I parse strings to integers, I use `Int32.TryParse()`.

I called this `Implicit` int size indication.

If I will want to make my application to be 64-bit I think there will be 2 scenarios:

- Rename all `Int32` to `Int64` and `INT` to `BIGINT`.

or

- Rename all `Int32` to `int` NOW and make int size indication be `Explicit`.

Which is better, how do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# and SQL Server both have fixed size of integers on all platforms. `int` in C# (which is simply an alias for `System.Int32` structure) and SQL Server is always 32 bits. Similarly, `long` in C# (an alias for `System.Int64` structure and SQL Server's `bigint` are always 64 bits regardless of the platform.

In C#, it's more natural to use the language defined alias for types (`int` instead of `Int32`, `long` instead of `Int64`) except for public method names (`ReadInt64` is preferable to `ReadLong`) as the method might be used in a language without or with different type aliases and it's better to use the .NET Framework name instead of the C# alias.

Comment: I don't know why but I was thinking that int is an alias for Int32 on x86 and for In64 on x64. Everything fell into place. Thanks!

Comment: Also I prefer static method calls from fully qualified names to aliases: Int32.TryParse() than int.TryParse()

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change your data types just because you are recompiling for a 64-bit platform

Comment: I mean not running as x64 process but supporting x64 memory size